# Gatsby.js problem with <Link>, no matter what I try

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I've a serious issue with the built-in `<Link>` component in Gatsby.js. I'm building a huge web project and everything was fine until I've tried to use `<Link>` instead of the standard `<a>` tag. I was frustrated to the point that I created a brand new, a blank project to test `<Link>` on a completely fresh project. Below you'll find the code. I'm trying to get from the index page to the contact page:

Index Page:

```
import React from "react"
import {Link} from "react"


const IndexPage = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Link Test</p>
      <a href="/contact/">Anchor to Contact</a>
      <Link to="/contact/">Link to Contact</Link>
 
    </div>
    )
  }
  export default IndexPage
```

Contact page:

```
import React from "react"

const Contact = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <p>Contact page</p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Contact;
```

When I use `<a>` tag everything is working smoothly but immediately after I'm trying to add `<Link>` in code I'm getting the same stupid error. It's only showing in browser not in the terminal of visual studio.

This is the error:

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `IndexPage`.
▶ 21 stack frames were collapsed.
(anonymous function)
/Users/piotr/Documents/Websites/LinkTest/LinkTest/.cache/app.js:133
  130 | const preferDefault = m => (m && m.default) || m
  131 | const Root = preferDefault(require(`./root`))
  132 | domReady(() => {
> 133 |   renderer(<Root />, rootElement, () => {
  134 |     apiRunner(`onInitialClientRender`)
  135 |   })
  136 | })
```

Please help because I've no idea what I should try next and I'm stuck on that bug for two days. Maybe I should update gatsby, node.js, and react on my computer? It's worth trying? :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to import `Link` from Gatsby, not from React:

```
import { Link } from "gatsby"
```

[Gatsby routing](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/gatsby-link/) extends from `@reach/router` (from React) but it adds useful enhancements specific to Gatsby, so it should be imported as a Gatsby dependency. All `props` are passed through to `@reach/router`’s `Link` component.

Keep in mind that, using a built-in anchor tag will refresh the whole page and the whole components (header, footer, etc), it won't be caught by the `@reach/router`.

While using `Link` component, it will only refresh the needed components, adding a more smooth behavior.

Comment: Thank you. What a stupid mistake... Now it works on my blank, test project. It's strange because in my main web project that I referred at the beginning of my question, I've {Link} imported from "gatsby.js" not from "react" and regardless it still doesn't work. I'll do more tests to find out where the problem is. But, after all i'm step further in solving this issue. Thank you.

Comment: It's still `import { Link } from "gatsby"` not from `gatsby.js`. Anyway, I'm glad to help. If the issue has been solved please accept the answer/upvote to close the issue :)

Comment: Of course it's gatsby without js. I have it correct in code, it was only a mistake in this particular comment. ;) I've too low rep to upvote your comment. I'll definitely come back to this topic after I get enough rep. I need only 4 more points. ;)